# Does $\epsilon^{-1}\chi_{\{|f(x)| < \epsilon\}}(x) \to 0$ pointwise a.e. as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be some integrable function on a bounded domain $\Omega$. Is it true that
$\epsilon^{-1}\chi_{\{|f(x)| < \epsilon\}}(x) \to 0$ pointwise a.e. as $\epsilon \to 0$?

I think it's true, even though the factor of $\epsilon^{-1}$ blows up because the measure of the set converges to zero. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only true if $f$ is almost everywhere nonzero, since $|f(x)| > 0$ implies $\chi_{\{|f|<\epsilon\}}(x) = 0$ eventually. At points where $f(x) = 0$, your function blows up!